# How to change icons based on theme in Qt C++? If available themes are dark or light

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt based text editor program. Its default theme is dark. I want to add a feature in which when the user selects a QAction for switchtheme(), the theme should toggle to light and the icons should also change according to light/dark. In my qrc file I have setup the structure as follows

```
:/images
|--> /theme_dark/
|--> /theme_light/
```

The icon file names have been kept same in both directories.

```
void MainWindow::switchTheme(const QString &themeName) 
{
//themeName will be "light" or "dark"

    QString image_path = ":/images/theme_"+themeName+"/"; 

    //Now maybe we can create a QStringList and append(filenames) to it.
    //Find all QActions in the toolbar and setIcon()?
}
```

The thing is that dark icons don't look good on dark theme and light ones don't look good on light theme. I want to know how to do this in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [QFileSelector](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfileselector.html):

```
QFileSelector selector;
QStringList extraSelectors;
extraSelectors << "theme_dark";
selector.setExtraSelectors(extraSelectors);
QString image = selector.select(":/images/myImage.png");
```

Qrc file structure should be:

```
:/images
|--> /+theme_dark/
|-----> myImage.png
|--> /+theme_light/
|-----> myImage.png
```

Comment: Actually inside the images/ directory, there are icons for the toolbar. So I have to individually set
`QAction *act = qobject_cast<QAction*>(ui->action_Name);`
`act->setIcon(QIcon(image_path+"image.png"));`
Is there are quicker way for this? Maybe setting the image name and Action name will help? 
For example, in a text editor there are toolbar buttons, when theme is toggled, all the tool buttons should change color too.

Comment: @Bhavyanshu You can get all your action with myToolbar->[actions()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#actions). Then  iterate over a QList<QActions*> and set icon: setIcon(QIcon(selector.select(":/images/"+actionsList.at(0).title+".png"))). In this case image name must be equal with action title. When you theme is togled, you should change extraSelectors and reset all icons.